# pods is forbidden: User tote-admin cannot list resource pods in API group at the cluster scope

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-security

I am creating a new user in my kubeadm kubernetes cluster named tote. so first I created a key:

```
openssl genrsa -out tote.key 2048
```

Then I created a CSR:

```
openssl req -new -key tote.key -subj "/CN=tote-admin" -out tote.csr
```

Finally, I am following kubernetes docs [in here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/certificate-signing-requests/) so:

A) I create a certificate signing request manifest:

```
apiVersion: certificates.k8s.io/v1
kind: CertificateSigningRequest
metadata:
  name: tote
spec:
  request: XXXXXX (based64 of the generated CSR)
  signerName: kubernetes.io/kube-apiserver-client
  usages:
  - client auth
```

B) Approve the CSR using kubectl:

```
kubectl certificate approve tote
```

C) Produce the crt certificate for tote user:

```
kubectl get csr tote -o jsonpath='{.status.certificate}'| base64 -d > tote.crt
```

Finally, when trying to list pods using apiserver url using tote user, it gives me error as the following:

```
curl https://172.31.127.100:6443/api/v1/pods --key tote.key --cert tote.crt --cacert /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt
```

And the response:

```
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {},
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "pods is forbidden: User \"tote-admin\" cannot list resource \"pods\" in API group \"\" at the cluster scope",
  "reason": "Forbidden",
  "details": {
    "kind": "pods"
  },
  "code": 403
```

Any help how to resolve this issue and allow user tote to access pods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Looks your Auth working, but user doesn't have the necessary permissions. You need to create RBAC permissions for the user you use. Refer to [Using RBAC Authorization](https://Kubernetes.io/doc/reference/access-auth-authz/rbac/)
2. And also try capturing certs from the .kube/config file.
   Like client-key data :

   echo -n "LS0....Cg==" | base64 -d > admin.key

Client-certificate-data :

```
echo -n "LS0...C==" | base64 -d > admin.crt
```

Certificate authority-data :

```
echo -n "LS0...g==" | base64 -d >ca.crt
```

Then use, `curl https://172.31.127.100:6443 \  --key admin.key \ --cert admin.crt  --cacert can.crt`